# how to find the "UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage" and "UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL" when downloading the image from net

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6

I want to get `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` and `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` when i download and save image to the photo album..

Can anyone suggest the proper method to find those 2 parameters?

if i use the method "

```
[library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[viewImage CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[viewImage imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error)
```

i will get "UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"
and if i use

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.imageURL]]], testOriginalImage, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil)
```

i will get "UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"

what to do to get both?

Comment: When getting the image from a server?

Comment: To be clear, you want to download an image from the Internet then save the image to the Photo Library. And then you want to get original image and reference URL values that you would normally get when selecting an image from the Photo Library using `UIImagePickerController`. Is that correct?

Comment: ya but cant v get directly the UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage and UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL at the same time? on click on download i want these 2parameters..

Comment: @Erway Software : ya i am getting image from server and saving it in photo library..

Comment: Please find the above edited answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call:

```
[library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[viewImage CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[viewImage imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error)
```

then you get/have both. The `assetURL` is the `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` and `viewImage` is the same as the `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage`.

Comment: how to get those? mean i want to print this.. how can i do that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want. What do you want to print?

Comment: according to ur answer if i use "[library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[viewImage CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[viewImage imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error)" i will get get Original image.. but i want to display as "UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage = "<UIImage: 0x1f50a6e0>""

Comment: The `viewImage` that you save is the original image. Print this out any way that you want.

Comment: the image URL and UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage = "<UIImage: 0x1f50a6e0>" is not getting matches, because viewImage is the image before saving and URL is what i am getting after saving.. i am getting an exception..